# Subsetting data frames according to lists in other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have three `data.frame`s, each with a column named `col`.
I want to filter out all rows of `DataFrame1`, whose values of `col` e.g. `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` appears in `DataFrame2`.
For that I am using

```
subset(DataFrame1, !(col %in% DataFrame2$col))
```

`DataFrame3` contains lists of values e.g. `a;b;c`, `c;d;a` in `col`.
Also in this case I want to filter DataFrame1 according to the occurrences of  `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in `DataFrame3`.

How do I expand the lists of values before I do the matching?

The data is roughly:

```
DataFrame1 DataFrame2 DataFrame3

col data   col data   col   data
a   1      a   6      a;b;c 8
b   2      b   7      c;d;b 9
c   3
d   4
e   5
```

After filtering with `DataFrame2` I have remaining in `DataFrame1`

```
col data
c   3
d   4
e   5
```

After filtering with `DataFrame3` I expect only to have in `DataFrame1`

```
col data
e   5
```

Data:

```
DataFrame1 <- data.frame(col = letters[1:5], data = 1:5)
DataFrame2 <- data.frame(col = letters[1:2], data = 6:7)
DataFrame3 <- data.frame(col = c("a;b;c", "c;d;b"), col = 8:9)
```

Comment: Please include reproducible (minimal) sample data for `DataFrame1` and `DataFrame2` along with your expected output. It's probably not a good idea to define a function called `Filter` as `Filter` is the name of a base R function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
DataFrame1 <- data.frame(col = letters[1:5], data = 1:5)
DataFrame2 <- data.frame(col = letters[1:2], data = 6:7)
DataFrame3 <- data.frame(col = c("a;b;c", "c;d;b"), col = 8:9)
```

Filtering step 1

```
df1 <- DataFrame1[!(DataFrame1$col %in% DataFrame2$col), ]
#  col data
#3   c    3
#4   d    4
#5   e    5
```

Filtering step 2

```
df2 <- df1[!(df1$col %in% unlist(strsplit(as.character(DataFrame3$col), ";"))), ]
df2
#  col data
#5   e    5
```

---

Or the same in a `dplyr` chain

```
library(dplyr)
DataFrame1 %>%
    filter(!(col %in% DataFrame2$col)) %>%
    filter(!(col %in% unlist(str_split(DataFrame3$col, ";"))))
#  col data
#1   e    5
```

Comment: For step 1, maybe `dplyr::anti_join(DataFrame1, DataFrame2, by="col")`